# reading large csv file that contains a column with large text values

Tags: sas

i am having an issue with a large data set when reading it into sas  that contains a review_text column with large text values. The first column review_id is listing the observation rather than the actual id. The other columns have wrong values and are being displaced within other variables.

```
 DATA review;
 INFORMAT review_id $50. ;
 INFORMAT review_text $5000. ;
 INFORMAT business_name $100. ;
 INFORMAT business_id $100. ;
 INFORMAT review_date mmddyy10. ;
 INFORMAT city $25. ;
 INFORMAT state $20. ;
 INFORMAT address $250. ;
 INFORMAT user_id $100. ; 
 INFORMAT user_name $100. ;
 INFORMAT friends $500. ;
 INFORMAT yelping_since mmddyy10. ;
 INFORMAT categories $100. ;
 INFILE 'C:\users\scott\desktop\yelp_food_reviews.csv' DELIMITER= ',' dsd LRECL=32767 FIRSTOBS=2;
 INPUT review_id $ review_text $ business_name $ business_id $  review_date review_ratingbusiness_rating num_biz_reviews city $ state $ address $ postal_code 8. latitude 8.10 longitude 8.10 mon_hours $ tues_hours $ wed_hours $ thurs_hours $ fri_hours $ sat_hours $ sun_hours $ user_id $ user_name $ user_reviews_given 8. ave_rating_given 4.1 friends $ yelping_since categories $ is_open 1.; 
 run;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD1Fx.png)

Comment: Please format your code. Paste it into EG, highlight and CTRL+I will format/indent your code automatically. Then you can paste it here formatted. It's not legible at he moment.

Comment: Check that each observation uses only one line in the source file. Perhaps the file was created in a way that caused a single observation to be wrapped onto multiple lines.  Or you have character strings that contain end of line characters in the middle of them.  The variable lengths in your program are not a problem, other than they increase the likelihood that the lines would have wrapped.

Comment: The observations are single line. For the review_text variable it contains multiple sentences.

Comment: You need to post the actual data lines and not a photograph of the result of running the datastep.  The `LIST` statement is helpful for debugging raw data. `data _null_; infile '.....' obs=5; input; list; run;`

Comment: Have you tried using GUESSINGROWS=;